# Different file permission error in "go test" and "bazel test"

Tags: go, testing, bazel

If a test wants to assert the file permission error, for example, writing to the root of file system, "go test" returns an `syscall.EACCES` error, while "bazel test" returns an `syscall.EPERM`. How to make the test passes in both "bazel test" and "go test"?

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/linzhp/bazel_examples/tree/master/permission).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the sandbox by using `bazel --spawn_strategy=standalone test //...`. I suspect this will work around the problem.

However, you may want to consider whether writing to `/` is the behavior that you want to test. If you need to run code on a different operating system or inside a Docker container, you'll get different behavior in this case, so you could think about testing a more predictable code path, or mocking out the file access layer to isolate your tests from it.